# Möbius transformations forming a group and isomorphism with $S_{3}(D_{6})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

My task is to prove that the Möbius transformations defined by 
$z,\frac{1}{z},1-z,\frac{1}{1-z},\frac{z}{z-1},\frac{z-1}{z}$ make up a group that is isomorphic to the group $S_{3}(D_{6})$. Identify the involutions i.e elements of order 2.
 We are also given a hint:

Show that the group permutes the elements, $0,1,\infty$

My solution.

1) First I made the composition of all the above functions and I got $\frac{1}{z}$ so I stay within the set thus the composition is an operation on this set.

2) associativity holds at the composition of functions is associative

3) as the identity element I have set the function $f(z)=z$ and I have checked with the other elements from the set.

4) I have found inverses to each of the elements and these are also elements of the set

Thus the set of these transformations together with $\circ$ is a group.

I have a problem though with the second part.

Firstly I have no idea what is the group $S_{3}(D_{6})$ how does it look like? What elements? Is this a direct product???
In practice it is much easier to show that two groups are non isomorphic, so I need to find a bijective function between my Möbius transformations and the $S_{3}(D_{6})$

Can someone help me with the identification of the involutions and proving the isomorphism?
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H$ be your group of Möbius transformations. We get a group homomorphism

$$H\rightarrow S_3, f\mapsto [x\mapsto f(x)],$$

where $S_3$ denotes the symmetric group in the three elements 0,1,$\infty$. Check that this is injective because only the identity fixes all the three elements. As $H$ has 6 elements and $S_3$ has also $3!=6$ elements, this map is even bijective, hence a group isomorphism.

Remark: Composing all functions in your solution doesn't suffice to show, that the set is closed. Each composition of two elements has to be an element of the set again.

By $S_3(D_6)$ they mean $S_3$ respectivly $D_6$ as $D_6$ is isomorphic to $S_3$. Take a look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group_of_order_6).

Comment: @@archipelago:Thanks I have computed the separate compositions as you suggested and we stay within the set. I do not understand the homomorphism you have created. Can you be more specific?

Comment: what do they mean by saying ''show that the group permutes $0,1,\infty$?? where do they come from? $S_{3}$ has elements $\{(1),(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)\}$

Comment: Let $M$ be a set. Define $S(M)$ as the group of all bijections from $M$ to $M$ with the usual composition of maps as operation. Then $S(M)$ is isomoprhic to $S(N)$ iff $M$ and $N$ have the same cardinality. $S_3$ is just $S(\{1,2,3\}$, in other words: Every group of permutations $S(M)$ is isomoprhic to $S_3$, if $M$ has three elements. My answer shows that $H$ is isomorphic to $S(\{0,1\infty\})$, hence to $S_3$.

Comment: thanks, you have made it easier to digest